# uksort help - using GROUP BY in single need help

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

Hello I have an array that looks like this after passing it through `uksort()`

```
    Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [job_id] => 4
            [job_title] => Supercar Test Driver
            [company_name] => McLaren
            [logo_small] => small_mclaren001.png
            [logo_large] => large_mclaren002.png
            [employer_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [job_id] => 3
            [job_title] => Recruitment Consultant - Driving
            [company_name] => MoovJob.com
            [logo_small] => small_rac001.png
            [logo_large] => large_rac002.png
            [employer_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [job_id] => 5
            [job_title] => Postal Worker / Post Person
            [company_name] => Royal Mail
            [logo_small] => small_royalmail001.png
            [logo_large] => large_royalmail002.png
            [employer_id] => 4
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [job_id] => 6
            [job_title] => Another Job
            [company_name] => MoovJob.com
            [logo_small] => small_rac001.png
            [logo_large] => large_rac002.png
            [employer_id] => 2
        )

)
```

However if in my SQL that returns this array I add GROUP BY company_name the final entry in the array dissapears, what I am trying to achieve is to place the job title under the company name, but only show the company name once, something similar to this,

> Company Name 1
>       Job Title 1
>       Job Title 2
>       Job Title 3
>
> Company Name 2
>   Job Title 4
>
> Company Name
>   Job Title 5     Job Title 6

I am trying to achieve this, by doing the followng in my view, however I can only show one vacancy, what am I doing wrong?

```
    <?php $oldemp   = "";?>
<?php foreach($jobs as $key => $value) : ?>
   <?php if ($oldemp != $value['company_name']) : ?>
        <?php $oldemp = $value['company_name']; ?>
        <section class="employer">
            <div class="job_holder">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/uploads/users/<?php echo $value['logo_large']; ?>" width="198" height="148" alt="<?php echo $value['company_name']; ?>"/>
                <dl>
                    <dt><?php echo count($key); ?></dt>
                    <dd>Matches</dd>
                </dl>
    <?php endif;?>
            <span> + <a href="/jobwall/getjob/<?php echo $value['job_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['job_title']; ?></a></span>
            </div>
        </section>
<?php endforeach; ?>


    function jobcmp($job1, $job2)
    {
        return strcmp($job1['company_name'], $job2['company_name']);
    }
```

Comment: This is a very long question that has a lot of details. This means that it requires a lot of effort for anyone to be able to even understand the core issue, let alone the specifics of your problem. It would be helpful to both us and you if you could recreate the problem in a much simpler situation, then ask us to solve the simple situation so that we don't have to learn all about your array.

Comment: What function are you using in `uksort`?

Comment: @glass robot please see my edited code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it would be possible to display the data using your approach I normally find it much more straightforward to create a second array in a more convenient format:

```
$groupedJobs = array();
foreach ($jobs as $data) {
    if (!isset($groupedJobs[$data['company_name']])) {
        $groupedJobs[$data['company_name']] = array();
    }
    $groupedJobs[$data['company_name']][] = $data;
}
```

this creates a new array using the company name as the key and that company's jobs in a nested array as the value, giving you something like this:

```
['MoovJob.com'] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                (job data)
            ),
        [1] => Array 
            (
                (etc.)
            )
    ),
['McLaren'] = Array
    (
        (etc)
    )
```

it is then much easier to loop through this array and display:

```
foreach ($groupedJobs as $companyName => $jobs) {
    echo $companyName;
    foreach ($jobs as $job) {
        echo $job['job_title'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this solution will be much more straightforward, but of course it is different approach that could be also used.

Comment: @Tim Fountain - I COULD KISS YOU!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the array is sorted by `job_title` `DESC` when it should be sorted by `company_name`

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not sorted correctly, employees with the same id should be one after another, for this array you should use usort method like this

```
usort($jobs, function($a, $b) {
 if($a['employee_id'] == $b['employee_id'] return 0;
 return ($a['employee_id'] < $b['employee_id']) ? 1 : -1;
})
```

The other way and I think the better one for your purpose is to use array_walk to prepare data for this section loop. Method below will remove duplicates from the table and join all job_titles for the same employees in a one key in primary employee record.

```
array_walk($jobs, function($emp, $index) use(&jobs) {
  static $primary;

  if(isset($primary[$emp['employee_id']) {
    $jobs[$primary[$emp['employee_id']]]['job_titles'][$emp['job_id'] = $emp['job_title'];
    unset($jobs[$index]);
  } else {
    $primary[$emp['employee_id']] = $index; //remeber index of primary entry
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks! However it is now outputting the second job an employer has outside it's `section` tag. Can this be fixed?

Comment: It's not problem with data you have error in your if statement where the <section> node is generated

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed the SQL query. However, the row that disappears is obviously related to the `GROUP BY company_name` you add.

When you add a `GROUP BY groupfield`, all rows with same `groupfield` "collapse" into one row. The columns that depend on that field, like `company_logo` can usually safely stay in the `SELECT` list. All others should be removed or changed to use an aggregate function like `SUM()` or `COUNT()`.

So, if you want to show numbers of jobs for every company, use `COUNT(job_id)` or `COUNT(*)`.

In your case, you have two options I think.

- First option is to NOT use `GROUP BY`, perhaps only `ORDER BY` and use PHP code to show what you need.
- Second option is to use `GROUP BY` and the aggregate `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

You can use it like:

```
SELECT
    company_name
  , GROUP_CONCAT( job_id
                  ORDER BY job_id
                  SEPARATOR ', ' )
      AS job_ids
  , GROUP_CONCAT( job_title
                  ORDER BY job_id
                  SEPARATOR ', ' )
      AS job_titles
  , GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(job_id, '-', job_title)
                  ORDER BY job_id
                  SEPARATOR ', ' )
      AS job_ids_and_titles
  , company_name
  , logo_small
  , logo_large
  , employer_id
FROM 
  ...
GROUP BY company_name
```